# PowerApps Modify Email-Screen Template

Tags: email, sharepoint, powerapps

Hi I have a PowerApp connected to Sharepoint List. The sharepoint list has 2 to columns that are lookup values of peson/group. Please see screenshot of powerapp display screen below.

[image: screenshot of Display Screen]

[image: screenshot of email template]

As I noted on the screenshot, I want have a button to send email. When the button is clicked, the email-screen template by PowerApps ([Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/screen-templates/email-screen-overview#show-different-data-for-people)) appears.

How do I autopopulate the Sponsor and BackUp Sponsor fields to the Email-Template, while still allowing the user to add more people if necessary?

I am not sure if this is needed but

[image: screenshot of fx]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to add the people into that control, but you could create a label that shows the people from your form above the "To" field in the email form and let the user enter additional recipients into the To field.

The icon that triggers the sending of the mail has underlying code in the **OnSelect** property. The first command in there sets the variable `_emailRecipientString` by concatenating several strings.

```
Set( _emailRecipientString, Concat(MyPeople, Mail & ";") );
```

Add your list of people as parameters inside the Concat() function.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted the answer [here](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/Modify-Recipients-using-Email-Template/td-p/535966)

here is the answer:
Add the code to the Notify/Send Email in the Display Screen

```
ClearCollect(selecteduser,
         ForAll(DataCardValue1.SelectedItems,Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:Email})),
         ForAll(DataCardValue2.SelectedItems,Office365Users.SearchUser({searchTerm:Email}))
        );
Clear(MyPeople); ForAll(selecteduser,Collect(MyPeople,Value))
```

I hope this helps someone else